# Добавить новое поле в словарь со значением из списка

Tags: python

Есть список списков

```
a = [[tiger, bear], [tit, sparrow], [perch, herring]]
```

И список словарей:

```
b = [{'n': 1, 'id': [3]}, {'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, {'n': 1, 'id': [1]}]
```

Необходимо в каждый словарь из списка добавить соответствующий ему список:

```
b = [{'n': 1, 'id': [3], 'animal': [tiger, bear]}, {'n': 4, 'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'animal': [tit, sparrow]}, {'n': 1, 'id': [1], 'animal': [perch, herring]}]
```

Пыталась использовать это, но работает не так как надо.

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b)):
        b[j]['animal'] = a[i]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если в лоб, то можно так:

```
res = []
for obj in zip(a, b):
    obj[1].update({'animal': obj[0]})
    res.append(obj[1])

print(res)
```

если однострочно, то с версии python 3.9 можно так:

```
b = [obj[1] | {'animal': obj[0]} for obj in zip(a, b)]
```

а с версии python 3.5 можно так:

```
b = [{**obj[1], 'animal': obj[0]} for obj in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

еще один способ "в лоб":

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i]['animal'] = a[i]
```